# How to filter genes from seuratobject in slotname @data?

Tags: r, regex, r-s4, seurat

I am working with a R package called "Seurat" for single cell RNA-Seq analysis and I am trying to remove few genes in seuratobject (s4 class) from slot name 'data'. There are several slots in this object as well that stores information associated to the slot 'data'.
The slot 'data' has Gene names in rows and cell IDs in columns with expression values of Genes corresponding each cell in the matrix.
I want to remove entire row based on unique gene names but retain the outcome in the object.

Example:

```
       Cell1 Cell2 Cell3  
GeneA2    5    9    2     
GeneA     3    1    0  
GeneA1    2    1    3
```

I want to remove row GeneA in the matrix.

I tried following but get errors:-

```
object<-SubsetRow(object@data, "GeneA", invert = TRUE)
```

and

```
GeneA<-grep(pattern = "^GeneA$", x = rownames(x = object@data), value = TRUE)
object@data<- object@data[!GeneA,]
```

Comment: Without any data this can only be considered an unclear (even opaque) question.  Although in second look ...  it may just be a newbie mistake of trying to access a slot with '$' when one should have used '@'. In which case it should be closed as a typo.

Comment: Apology for being unclear. I edited my ques with example. I used the $ to get unique Gene name.Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: It does NOT. (The "$" in a greppish pattern is the end of a character value.) [Edit] your question: Start with a `library` call. Work on a dataset from the package and create an object similar to your own. Then ask a question with specific reference to the data-objects that we will all share in our workspaces.

Comment: Working on the cd_genes object in the examples on the Seurat::SubsetRow help page there is no slot named `data`.

Comment: Did you mean the slot `@.Data`? (Note the dot and capital D). That is a slot inherent in (almost) every S4 object, and is not explicitly named. Also, please post the errors you get --- it will help us to identify what went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that you are working with something similar to the pbmc_small data object that os loaded with the Seurat package. The look at the example on the `?SubsetRow` help page:

```
# Installing the package:Seurat does install quite a few additonal packages
library(Seurat)
cd_genes <- SubsetRow(data = pbmc_small@raw.data, code = 'CD')
str(cd_genes)
#=================
Formal class 'dgTMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:209] 0 5 6 9 5 8 9 10 15 5 ...
  ..@ j       : int [1:209] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 16 80
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:16] "CD79B" "CD79A" "CD19" "CD180" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:80] "ATGCCAGAACGACT" "CATGGCCTGTGCAT" "GAACCTGATGAACC" "TGACTGGATTCTCA" ...
  ..@ x       : num [1:209] 1 4 1 2 4 2 2 1 1 4 ...
  ..@ factors : list()
 #===========
rownames(x = cd_genes@data)
```

> Error in rownames(x = cd_genes@data) : 
>    no slot of name "data" for this object of class "dgTMatrix"

So there is no @data slot in that object

Instead just use rownames on cd_genes:

```
rownames(x = cd_genes)
 [1] "CD79B"   "CD79A"   "CD19"    "CD180"   "CD200"   "CD3D"    "CD2"     "CCDC104" "CD3E"   
[10] "CD7"     "CD8A"    "CD14"    "CD1C"    "CD68"    "CD9"     "CD247"
```

So this removes the name "CD200" from that object:

```
> object<-SubsetRow(pbmc_small@raw.data, code="^CD200$", invert = TRUE)
> str(object)
Formal class 'dgTMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:4453] 1 5 8 11 22 29 32 33 35 37 ...
  ..@ j       : int [1:4453] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 229 80
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:229] "MS4A1" "CD79B" "CD79A" "HLA-DRA" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:80] "ATGCCAGAACGACT" "CATGGCCTGTGCAT" "GAACCTGATGAACC" "TGACTGGATTCTCA" ...
  ..@ x       : num [1:4453] 1 1 3 1 1 4 1 5 1 1 ...
  ..@ factors : list()
> "CD200" %in% rownames(object)
[1] FALSE
> "CD200" %in% rownames(pbmc_small@raw.data)
[1] TRUE
```

There is a `data`-named slot in `Seurat`-objects but once you have extracted it, there is no longer a `data`-slot in that object:

```
slotNames(pbmc_small)
 [1] "raw.data"     "data"         "scale.data"   "var.genes"    "is.expr"      "ident"       
 [7] "meta.data"    "project.name" "dr"           "assay"        "hvg.info"     "imputed"     
[13] "cell.names"   "cluster.tree" "snn"          "calc.params"  "kmeans"       "spatial"     
[19] "misc"         "version"  

 slotNames(pbmc_small@data)
[1] "i"        "p"        "Dim"      "Dimnames" "x"        "factors"
```

Based on the comment it appears communication of the issue is not complete. If the question is how to modify an existing slot value then just use `@<-` as exemplified here:

```
pbmc_small2 <- pbmc_small
pbmc_small2@data <- SubsetRow(data = pbmc_small@data, code = 'CD')
```

I'm not sure it's safe, however. The dimensions of the `@data` slot are now different than the dimensions of the `@raw.data` slot and other features may not match, although I don't know enough about that structure to be sure. The safe way to use S4 objects is to rely on the functions provided by package authors rather than mucking with low-level stuff like slots. Obviously, they wanted you to be able to subset from sparse matrices, but whether they wanted you to assign them back to slots is not so clear.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I did in my example but with object@data instead of object@raw.data. SubsetRow to both of them changes the class to dgTMatrix apparently and then I loose the other slotNames that is the metadata pertaining to raw.data and dataslot. Hence, I can't use the output with downstream Seurat function.

Comment: I don't get it. You said you were getting errors. I showed how to remove rows based on a pattern. No errors. The SubsetRow-function will work with either the data or the raw.data leaf of the object. Yes. You do lose the other metadata. If you want to create a subset with metadata that is the same as the larger set (which is probably not safe or accurate) then you can make a copy and assign to a slot with the `@<-`

Comment: Solved it. I was assigning the output matrix to the slot instead of just gene names. Thats why I was getting an error. You were helpful.Thank you very much.

Comment: The "SO-way" is not to leave a [solved] comment, but rather to apply a checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

try the command below?

`keep= c(!rownames(object) %in% c("GeneA"))
object <- subset(x = object,features =c(1:(dim(object)[1]))[keep])`